# Exibir uma caixa de alerta ao carregar a página

Tags: angular, alert, alertdialog

Estou trabalhando com Angular e preciso exibir uma caixa de alerta ao carregar o html de um componente, porém eu só consigo fazer isso a partir de um click de botão, porém eu preciso que o alerta se abra assim que a pagina seja carregada, sem necessidade de interação com objeto algum.
Segue meu código html:

```
<form #entryForm="ngForm" class="form">
 <mat-card class="caixa fadeIn animated">
  <div class="container">

        <audio class="audio" id="voz" controls="controls">
            <source src="assets/voz1WAV.wav" type="audio/wav" />
            <source src="assets/voz1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
          Your browser does not support the audio element.
          </audio>
        <br><br><br><br><br>

      <label class="G"> G <label class="fonteQuestionario">(Grau global da disfonia)</label> </label>

        <mat-radio-group class="posicaoG" name="G">
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="0" disabled>0</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="1" disabled>1</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="2" disabled>2</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="3" disabled>3</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <br>

      <label class="G"> R <label class="fonteQuestionario">(Rugosidade)  </label> </label>
      <mat-radio-group class="posicaoR" name="R">
        <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="0">0</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="3">3</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
    <br>

    <label class="G"> B <label class="fonteQuestionario">(Soprosidade)  </label> </label>
    <mat-radio-group class="posicaoB" name="B">
        <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="0">0</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="3">3</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
    <br>
        <label class="G"> A <label class="fonteQuestionario">(Astenia)  </label> </label>
        <mat-radio-group class="posicaoA" name="A">
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="0">0</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="3">3</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
        <br>
         <label class="G"> S <label class="fonteQuestionario">(Tensão)  </label> </label>
         <mat-radio-group class="posicaoS" name="S">
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="0">0</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="3">3</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
        <br>
         <label class="G"> I <label class="fonteQuestionario">(Instabilidade)  </label> </label>
         <mat-radio-group class="posicaoI" name="I">
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="0">0</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="1">1</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="2">2</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button class="margem" value="3">3</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
  </div>
  <div><br><br><br><br><br></div>

  <button class="previous"mat-mini-fab color="accent"> 
    <mat-icon>keyboard_backspace</mat-icon>
</button>

  <button class="next"mat-mini-fab color="accent"> 
    <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
</button>    

    </mat-card>
```

Preciso que assim que esse formulário seja chamado, seja exibido uma caixa de alerta na tela, para que eu possa passar certas informações.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, tudo bem?

Me desculpe se eu estiver errado, mas acredito que seja utilizando o **ngOnInit**, você pode fazer da seguinte forma;

Vá até o arquivo **ts** do seu componente e adicione o método ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit () {
  alert ('Componente Iniciado') // Seu código aqui
}
```

Você pode ver mais na biblioteca do [Angular](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)

Comment: Muito boa sua solução! Porém ainda tem um pequeno problema, antes do formulário eu possuo uma tela de introdução de conceitos, então quando eu clico no botão "next" que me levaria pra telande formulário, a caixa de diálogo ja se abre na tela de introdução, entes mesmo de alterar pra tela de formulário

Comment: coloca no constructor

Comment: ele carrega dps do onInit

Comment: Coloquei no contrutor e o problema persistiu :/